# According to Korach, why was Moshe still the leader?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, parshat-korach, korach

Korach and his companions accused Moshe of inventing Mitzvot and of placing himself and his favorites in places of high importance. Didn`t they think that God Himself would remove Moshe from his post if he was really doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadal [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Shadal_on_Numbers.16.1.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) explain like that:

> והנה קרח ועדתו מאמינים היו כי יש אלהים בישראל, ושהאל הה הנקרא ה' נשבע לאבותם להורישם את הארץ, ושהוא העושה להם אותות ומופתים; אבל היו מאמינים כי האל על ידי עבודות מיוחדות הוא כורת ברית עם כהניו וחכמיו היודעים דרכי עבודתו, ועושה להם רצונם. והנה האמינו כי משה פועל גבורות בכח האל, אבל האמינו ג"כ שהאל מתפתה ושומע למשה בעשותו לפניו העבודות הרצויות לו, וא"כ עכשו שהוקם המשכן ונודעו משפטי הקרבנות ודרכי העבודה הרצויים לפני ה', יוכל כל אדם להיות כהן ונביא מבלעדי אהרן ומשה, והנה קרח היה מתנשא לאמר אני אהיה כהן ונביא, וה' יענה אותי בנסים ונפלאות כאשר ענה את משה ואת אהרן, אחרי אשר אעבוד עבודתו כמצֻוֶה מפיו; ולמה אראה את משה ואת אחיו בגדולה, ואני ואחי נהיה להם לנושאי כלים? ומשה ראה את כוונתו ואמר להם קחו לכם מחתות ותראו אם העבודה והקטרת היא מקובלת לפניו מצד עצמה, יהיה המקטיר מי שיהיה, או אם רצון האל הוא שיהיה המקטיר איש מיוחד הנבחר והחביב לו.

> ... And behold, Korah and his congregation believed that there is a God in Israel, and that the God who is called the Lord swore to their fathers to inherit the land, and that He performs signs and wonders for them. However, they believed that God, through special deeds, establishes a covenant with His priests and wise men who know His ways of worship, and He fulfills their desires. They believed that Moses performed mighty acts through the power of God, but they also believed that God can be persuaded and listens to Moses when he performs the desired deeds before Him. Therefore, now that the Tabernacle has been established and the laws of sacrifices and the desired ways of worship before God have been revealed, anyone can be a priest and a prophet apart from Aaron and Moses. And behold, Korah was elevating himself, saying, 'I will be a priest and a prophet, and God will answer me with miracles and wonders, just as He answered Moses and Aaron, after I perform His service as commanded by Him. Why should I not be seen with the same greatness as Moses and Aaron? Why should my brother and I be excluded from carrying the sacred vessels?' Moses perceived his intention and said to them, 'Take fire pans and see if the incense offering is accepted by God on its own merits, regardless of who offers it. Whether it is the chosen and beloved individual or any other person, the one who offers it will be the accepted one if it is God's will.

So he thought that indeed it was Hashem's will, but that anyone with the good actions could become prophet and/or kohen.

Answer (score 3):

Korach didn't believe God appointed Moses or gave the Torah.  The Yerushalmi says:

> At that moment, Korach said that the Torah is not from Heaven, nor is Moses a [true] prophet, nor Aaron a High Priest.  [Sanhedrin Y 10:1]

Answer (score -1):

Korach's main objection was the nepotism he saw and how strange it is that the holiest people all happen to be the relatives of Moshe. The only prophetess we hear of in the Torah is Miriam. And Aaron, despite being the hands that ultimately made the calf and who seemingly is pardoned while  3,000 other men were put to death by the sword. And as if that wasn't enough, Korach and his members witnessed Aaron's sons die and be consumed by God for offering a strange fire. Korach was implying that Moses and Aaron had taken too much and might not be fit for the job. They had a legitimate question: compared to this idol making High Priest and his two sons who couldn't even handle being priests, couldn't we do a better job?

But Korach knew why Moses was the leader. Moses was the leader because he did the work, he followed through on everything that he said he would do. And Moses was the teacher of a law that Korach was accepting. But as Moses pointed out, Korach was truly after the priesthood, not the seat of Moses.

Separately, Moses is upset that Korach would imply that Moses was taking advantage of the congregation, but he knew Korach had his sights on the priesthood.

Numbers 16:10-11

י  וַיַּקְרֵב, אֹתְךָ, וְאֶת-כָּל-אַחֶיךָ בְנֵי-לֵוִי, אִתָּךְ; וּבִקַּשְׁתֶּם, גַּם-כְּהֻנָּה. 10 and that He hath brought thee near, and all thy brethren the sons of Levi with thee? and will ye seek the priesthood also?
יא  לָכֵן, אַתָּה וְכָל-עֲדָתְךָ--הַנֹּעָדִים, עַל-יְהוָה; וְאַהֲרֹן מַה-הוּא, כִּי תלונו (תַלִּינוּ) עָלָיו.   11 Therefore thou and all thy company that are gathered together against the LORD--; and as to Aaron, what is he that ye murmur against him?'